# Get insights using Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I'm using the code below on Graph API Explorer to get my Facebook campaigns insights, but I can't get the number of **page likes** and the **conversions**. How can I do that?

```
act_[ACCOUNT-ID]/insights?fields=spend,campaign_name&level=campaign
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set:

```
action_breakdowns=action_type
```

and add the 'actions' to the fields. One of the action type is 'like'